# C++ using execvp with string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm writing a program to execute Unix commands with any amount of arguments. I have no problem receiving input and making tokens as I use regular strings. However, execvp will only accept an array of pointers and I'm not sure how to go about converting the array of strings to this. Here's what I have:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
while (true)
{
    int argc = 0;
    std::istringstream iss;
    std::string command;
    std::cout << "$> ";
    getline(std::cin, command);
    iss.str(command);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= command.length(); i++)
    {
        if (command[i] == ' ' || command[i] == '\0')
        {
            argc++;
        }
    }
    std::string arr[argc+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        iss >> arr[i];
    }
    if (arr[0].compare("quit"))
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        char*argv[argc+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        {
            argv[i] = arr[i].c_str(); //This line is wrong
        }
        argv[argc] = NULL;
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I've tried various methods and can't figure out how to convert a string to a char array in the proper manner. Methods like strcpy won't work because the length of each argument will vary. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about making your array const to match the fact that c_str() returns a const ? Can you show us the error message by the way ?

Comment: I've tried adding const to the array but I'm getting "invalid conversion from ‘const char**’ to ‘char* const*’". But placing const anywhere else only leads to more errors. The inital message without the const says "invalid conversion from const char* to char*" which makes sense but the rest is throwing me.

Comment: Ok, you mean later in the execvp() ?

Answer (score 2):

You have very small mistakes.

Replace:

1. `argv[i] = arr[i].c_str();` with `argv[i] = const_cast<char*>(arr[i].c_str());`
2. `if(arr[0].compare("quit"))` with `if(!arr[0].compare("quit"))`

And you are good to go, and this would work in any compiler.
Run [here](http://ideone.com/UWWgXO)

But I have some advice to make it using fork so it won't run only one command at a time.

Example [here](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/exec.html)

Comment: Yes ! But casting a way const, be it with `(char*)` or with `argv[i] = const_cast<char*>(arr[i].c_str());` wouldn't protect you anymore against unauthorized overwriting.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! Totally forgot that const_cast was a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your array is holding `char*`, while `std::string::c_str()` returns `const char*`. It can't be stored in your array, because it would lose const-ness.

If you're using a C++11 compliant compiler, you can use `&arr[i][0]` to obtain a non-const pointer to the internal string buffer.

If you aren't using a C++11 compliant compiler, the internal buffer may not be null-terminated, so your only option is to use `new` or `malloc` to allocate correctly sized buffers, then `strcpy` the strings into them.

```
char* buffer = new char[arr[i].length() + 1];
strcpy(buffer, arr[i].c_str());
argv[i] = buffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure `null` terminator at the end of each string in the array this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    iss >> arr[i];
    arr[i].push_back('\0');
}
```

Then you can simply capture pointer to the first character of each string. Clean and safe, without any `const_cast`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    argv[i] = &arr[i][0];
}
```